# Qt Creator - exclude warnings for Qt and 3rd party libs

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, gcc, qt-creator

Is there a way to exclude compiler warnings for 3rd party libraries, i.e. Qt and other external libraries ("external" in this context means "not my source code").

I do **not** want to disable a certain warning type (I know how to do so), but only see warnings for my code.

In an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956623/356726) I have found an approach to surround external libs by `#pragma` , only I need a gcc and vc++ compliant solution. Are there any better alternatives for Qt Creator?

Comment: I think you will find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199505/is-there-a-possibility-to-pass-includes-via-isystem-when-using-qmake

Comment: Looks good for gcc, need to find the corresponding option for vc++